# (Rails 4) How to make nested named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a few nested models (states, regions (belongs to states), sites (belongs to states and regions) ) and i'd like routes that are more semantic. Instead of 'cool.com/states/1/regions/2/sites/5' I'd like 'cool.com/california/northern/sanfransiscosite'

is this achievable in rails 4?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a combination of the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem and some custom routes in your routes file such as:

```
match 'states/:id/:region_id/:site_id' => 'states#show'
```

Comment: Nice! I was able to pivot on this and not use friendly_id.

I just created this route:
get ':state_slug/:region_slug/:site_slug', to: 'site#show'
(and my show controller runs @site = Site.find_by_slug(params[:site_slug]) )

Comment: One thing to note from this answer is that with rails 4 you need to specify a http method. I don't think a match all routes is possible unless you specifically specify via: :all

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a look at the rails guide for nested resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thanks Matt -- I have nested resources set up now but I want cleaner URLs -- instead of cool.com/states/1/region/1 i'd like cool.com/california/northerncalifornia.

Comment: The nesting has little to do with that the ID's are, override the to_param method in your models to what you would like it to be, or like suggested use friendly_id.